# Location Services Working On Simulator But Not Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cllocationmanager

I am running an app that uses the users location to grab events from a database. When I run the app on the simulator it grabs the users location perfectly however on my phone after it sends the request and I allow it. It just stops and nothing loads.

This is the function that I use to grab the location. It uses a third part library called SwiftLocation

```
struct LocationService {
    static func getUserLocation(completion: @escaping (CLLocation?) -> Void){
        print("Atttempting to get user location")
        //May need location manager function
        //may need to change to always for significant location to work
        Locator.requestAuthorizationIfNeeded(.whenInUse)

        //It then delivers location updates to your app only when the user’s position changes by a significant amount, such as 500 meters or more.
        //To subscribe to significant location changes, use the method Locator.subscribeSignificantLocations. This instructs location services to begin monitoring for significant location changes, which is very power efficient. The block will execute indefinitely (until canceled), once for every new updated location regardless of its accuracy.

       // Note: If there are other simultaneously active location requests or subscriptions, the block will execute for every location update (not just for significant location changes).

        Locator.subscribeSignificantLocations(onUpdate: { newLocation in
            print("New location \(newLocation)")
            completion(newLocation)
        }) { (err, lastLocation) -> (Void) in
            print("Failed with err: \(err)")
        }
    }  
}
```

This is my info.plist[image]

Any idea what could be wrong?
It doesn't go to failed or anything it literally just stops.

Comment: check `Settings/YourApp/Location`, what do you see?

Comment: it says "while using the app" @AndreaMugnaini

Comment: what is your point @AndreaMugnaini

Comment: Note that: `user’s position changes by a significant amount, such as 500 meters or more`. So maybe it's just working as expected, hence you are not getting any update.

Comment: yeah but shouldn't it do the same on the simulator? @AndreaMugnaini

Comment: I guess it's not exactly the same, eg: on your simulator you might fake the position anytime, you can't achieve the same on a physical device

Comment: yeah that was it @AndreaMugnaini

Comment: Anyway, try this on the target configuration: Core Location->Flag true on Allow location simulation->change the default location. Do such stuff running on the device from Xcode.

Comment: that's weird that it would work on the simulator but not the phone smh @AndreaMugnaini

Comment: Might want to put that code inside a `class`, not a `struct`.

Comment: Does the records in the database depends on the user's location? I think you said yes. Is it possible that the user's actual position through the iPhone does not have any records in the database.

Comment: sorry I am late @azamsharp but I heard it was bad practice to store the users location in the database. So what I did was get it using the third party library and query using geofire and location

Comment: @Adrian why ? what are the benefits and the tradeoffs?